# While query data (web scraping) from a website with Python, how to avoid being blocked by the server?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, export-to-csv

I was trying to using python requests and mechanize to gather information from a website. This process needs me to post some information then get the results from that website. I automate this process using for loop in Python. However, after ~500 queries, I was told that I am blocked due to high query rate. It takes about 1 sec to do each query. I was using some software online where they query multiple data without problems. Could anyone help me how to avoid this issue? Thanks!

No idea how to solve this.

--- I am looping this process (by auto changing case number) and export data to csv....

After some queries, I was told that my IP was blocked.

Comment: Wait longer between queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. Optimum randomized delay time between requests.
2. Randomized real user-agents for
   each request.
3. Enabling cookies.
4. Using a working proxy pool and
   selecting a random proxy for each request.